# Image resizing not working?

Tags: php

I used to do this by percentages although now I am looking to do it by Pixels instead, although after trial, the images don't seem to be resizing? And I am not sure why?

```
$get_resize_width = '225';
$get_resize_height = '150';

$info = getimagesize($file);

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);

$new_width = $get_resize_width;
$new_height = $get_resize_height;

if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);

$image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$photo = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
imagecopyresampled($image, $photo, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($image, $newfile, $img_quality);

$origional_image = $file;
$compressed_image = $newfile;
```

I have tried adding `px` to the end of the variables although this doesn't seem to make a difference?

Comment: You need to use the correct functions based on the mime. `imagecreatefromjpeg`, `imagejpeg` need to be if blocks.

Comment: Do you check your code before you publish it here? Lots of things are double, and therefore do not make sense.